# State of the art in register allocation for straight-line programs

Tags: algorithms, optimization, compilers, program-optimization, resource-allocation

**TL;DR: I'm looking for the fastest known algorithm to perform optimal register allocation (optimal in the sense of minimizing the number of spills and reloads) for straight-line programs.**

#### Context

I am working on an optimized implementation of certain computational kernels. I have a code generator which outputs variants of the code in which certain parameters are tuned, and tries to find the fastest implementation among these. The generated code is always a straight-line program, with no branches, in SSA form.

Because I have to generate many variants (say, millions to billions) in search of the fastest one, it is crucial that the cost of generating each variant is as small as possible. On the other hand, the ultimate goal is to obtain the fastest possible implementation, so the quality of the generated code should not be compromised to speed up code generation.

In particular, this code is meant to run in a "simple" CPU: in-order and non-superscalar. While in modern superscalar OoO processors one can perform loads and stores at potentially zero cost (if there aren't too many of them, and they're performed far enough ahead to hide their latency), this is not the case for the CPU I am targeting: every instruction costs (at least) one cycle. Also, the working set of the program is much larger than the register file size, so some spills and reloads will necessarily happen, and each of these will have a definite cost in execution time. Thus, one of the optimizations I'm looking to perform is to minimize the number of spills and reloads.

[This (old: 1989) paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/559775) claims to do exactly what I need, but I have been unable to find a more recent reference. I would expect that someone would have improved upon this in the intervening ~35 years.

**My question:** what is the state of the art in optimal register allocation for straight-line programs? Research papers would be great, and actual implementations (i.e. an accompanying GitHub repository to a paper) would be perfect, even if a little behind the state of the art.